# Can't fit photo in a modal window without overflowing a screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with fitting my image in a modal window. When image `height` is lager then the screen `height` user can scroll the modal window. Can someone tell me what can I use to fit it in a screen size without overflowing and with disabled scroll. I've tried to limit the size of a image by `max-height: 600px`, but the [proportions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMXsA.jpg) are terrible.

```
.modal {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: white;
    display: table;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.modal .modal-photo {
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2rem auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

### How it currently looks:

[image: How it is looking now]

### How I want it to look (area bounded by red border):

[image: What I want (picture with red border)]

Comment: have a look at the object-fit property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/ you will still need to set a max-height but you can choose how it fills the available area

Comment: Have you considered making the image the background of your modal?

Comment: You probably need to remove `height` from `.modal .modal-photo {...}` or make it `auto`. You are now defining a square for the photo, but the photo you use is not square. But, your problem cannot be reproduced. Checkout [reprex].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was [fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He7MY.jpg) by changing `max-width` to `100%` and `max-height` to `600 px` in a `.modal .modal-photo`

```
    .modal {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: white;
    display: table;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
    }

    .modal .modal-photo {

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    padding: 2rem auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Thanks for everyone who participated